# Next.js 14.1 Receive external form POST & output rendered element

Tags: post, next.js, next.js14

I'm still in the process of learning Next.js so bear with me.

I'm building a small application that will provide a login for an SSO authentication layer. The flow includes the user being bounced around a bit between applications, eventually landing on my Next.js application with a POST request.

For clarity, a third-party application is sending the user to my application with a POST request. This isn't an AJAX request intended for an API. It's a document request intending to have an HTML response, like submitting a raw HTML form in ye olde days.

What's the optimum way to receive this POST request and respond in a way that supports rendering elements?

`./app/sign-in/page.tsx` is only reachable via `GET`

`./app/sign-in/route.tsx` with a `POST` function seemingly can't render elements for its response

I know I can have a `POST` route receive the request and convert the `POST` variables into parameters for a `GET` redirect to a page for rendering, but this feels very hacky and conceptually cheating, not to mention the `POST` contains a large payload of time-limited, security-sensitive data I'd prefer not becoming visible in the URL.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. This is feeling like a very classic use case without an officially supported solution.